# XmlPullParser fetching xml from url

Tags: android, xml, parsing

So i am parsing XML with xmlpullparser. I stored it localy in android project, but problem is that i want to load xml from url. What to change in code bellow?

Thanks in advance

```
public String getItemFromXML(Activity activity) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException{
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
Resources res = activity.getResources();
XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.items);
xpp.next();
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
        if (xpp.getName().equals("Prostorija")){
            stringBuffer.append(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "v") + "\n");
        }
        if (xpp.getName().equals("prozor")){
            stringBuffer.append(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "v") + "\n");
        }
        if (xpp.getName().equals("vrata")){
            stringBuffer.append(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "v") + "\n");
        }
        if (xpp.getName().equals("tempratura")){
            stringBuffer.append(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "v") + "\n");
        }
    }
    eventType = xpp.next();
}
return stringBuffer.toString();}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

> We recommend XmlPullParser, which is an efficient and maintainable way to parse XML on Android. Historically Android has had two implementations of this interface:

```
KXmlParser via XmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser().
ExpatPullParser, via Xml.newPullParser().
```

Once you have a XmlPullParser, you can set stream to it with `setInput` method.

Answer (score 0):

please see the below link ... xml parser from url

[Xml Parser from URL](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/)

Comment: it is not using Xmlpullparser